# How do I turn off the automatic update of the system time on

Tags: system, clock

I am running ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I would like to temporarily set the time on my system, but when I run:

```
sudo date 04291200
date
```

for a second or two, the response from clock will show the date/time that I have set, but then the system resets the system clock from the internet.

I got around the problem by disconnecting from the network, but this is just a workaround. I checked to see if the network time protocol was running, but ntpd did not show anywhere. I did a search on the internet, but I could not find any pointers on how to set the clock without having the system automatically resetting the clock.

Can someone explain how I can turn the automatic feature off/on?

Answer (score 1):

System time updating is handled by `ntp`, which is stopped via

```
sudo systemctl stop ntp.service
```

and (re-)started by

```
sudo /usr/sbin/ntpdate-debian
sudo systemctl start ntp.service
```

However, setting the time backward has been known to have unintended consequences.

Comment: `Failed to stop ntp.service: Unit ntp.service not loaded.` This command doesn't seem to work with 16.04.2...

Comment: My expectation is that what you suggested would work, that is, if ntp were controlling the setting of the system date/time. But as I mention in my original question, ntp is not running on this system, at least as far as I can tell. There is no ntp software in /etc and when I run "ps -elf | grep ntp" the ntpd daemon does not show up in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the time synchronization on and off with

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
timedatectl set-ntp false
```

There is no need for root privileges to run this commands.

Comment: That solution is a bit scary. If the os is running on a shared machine, I would not want just anyone to turn ntp on or off.  I would prefer someone who has root privileges.  But I did try it, and got an error message, because ntp is not running on this os.

Comment: @JimAnderson The scary things are the things you have to do with root privileges.

Comment: @JimAnderson Here is a link about the suggested comments: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html BTW I cant change the system time with `sudo date 04291200` without running the second suggested comment first. Also `ntp`-service is not running on my system.

Comment: I tried `timedatectl set-ntp false` and got the following error message: `** (process:4209): WARNING **: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
Error registering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
Failed to set ntp: The name org.freedesktop.timedate1 was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: Does it look like the time service is not configured properly? But the time and date are set, I just can't change either date or time. I rarely have to do this, so maybe I should just close this issue.

Comment: @JimAnderson The suggested commands work on my system, and I think it is the way we should do it. The commands in the other answer would have been valid in earlier version of Ubuntu, but with change to systemd we should use the suggested commands in my answer. I think your system is somhow misconfigured. This might be above my horizon though. You should ask a new question `Why timedatectl does not work on my system?` to get more attraction on this topic. providing a link this (recent) question in your new question would be a good idea.