# Attempting to disable NTP with timedatectl results in "Failed to set ntp: The name org.freedesktop.timedate1 was not provided by any .service file"

Tags: systemd, time

I have an earlier question at [How do I turn off the automatic update of the system time on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910257/how-do-i-turn-off-the-automatic-update-of-the-system-time-on/917437). My problem was not resolved but it was recommended that I repost with this question.

My understanding is that with Ubuntu 16.04.2, timedatectl should be available to turn the system clock off and back on. Currently, when I run:

```
timedatectl set-ntp false
```

I get the following message:

```
Failed to set ntp: The name org.freedesktop.timedate1 was not provided by any .service files
```

My guess is that I must install some additional software, but that is only a guess and I don't know what software, if any, is missing. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 and using openbox with it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may be trying to disable something which is not currently enabled. Check the output of this command:

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
```

Look at the `Loaded:` line. Does it say "enabled" or "disabled"?
Look at the `Active:` line. Does it say "active" or some other value?

If the service is not active and not enabled, then your goal has already been accomplished.